# node, iterate mysql rows, call another mysql query using the async lib

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I've come a cropper with some async stuff, I know the reason. I belive my loop variable is out of scope when I run async.serial.

The code iterates through a series of rows from one database using the mysql module, and based on some value calls another query and appends the result to a document. My basic code is

```
//data access
LoadData: function(query, callback) {
 //mysql connection stuff
 connection.connect();
    var query = connection.query(sp, function(err, rows, fields){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        connection.end();
        callback(rows);
    });
});
// this works fine, my call back is fired without any problems

//controller
//load data from mysql and proceed when the callback has been called
LoadData(sp, function (retdata) {
var tasks = [];
for i=0;i<retdata.length;i++)
 {
  tasks.push(function(callback){
  LoadData(retdata[i], function (ret) {
  //each row from the original results will call a new store proc, and append the results to a    file
 //other stuff
  }
  callback();
  }) 
 }
});

async.serial(tasks,function(){...})
//there should be 3 unique rows from the first data set, however the same data is written to file 3 times - so it's a variable issue, just not sure how best to tackle this - I'm using to C# lol
//I tried the async foreachserial() that didn't work either
```

thanks for any help guys

Comment: You're probably better off using `async.eachSeries()` with `retdata` instead of creating a separate function for each item in `retdata`.

Comment: thanks eachSeries and a change to callback names seems to have done the trick! 
I've changed it to use mapSeries as variable scope is an issue at the moment and I need access to the final variable. Just need to figure out how to get the variable passed to mapSeries now. cheers 
add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off using `async.eachSeries()` with `retdata` instead of creating a separate function for each item in `retdata`. Making this change should simplify things a bit and should be more efficient than `async.serial()`.